# Formula does not show superscript character

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting

I have a formula which I want to show a result which includes a superscript character, but I cannot get said character as superscript.

Normally I would just enter text into a cell and I can select just the character I want superscripted, right click, `Format Cells` and choose `Superscript`. However the `Format Cells` option is greyed out when I have a formula in the cell.

The formula in question is along the lines of;

`="Area = "&A1"&"mm2"`

To ideally give me an output of;

[image]

I have even tried putting the mm^2 text in its own cell and referencing that in the formula but still no joy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of superscripting the normal 2, use the dedicated character, which is common to most fonts.
[image: Windows character map]

Comment: found on most azerty keyboards next to the 1 button